# Android OpengGL es assets loading

Tags: android

I'm now working on an Android game, use GLSurfaceView and NDK.
  Now I have a problem, when loading scene assets( textures, models and on), just at this time, phone call income, my app enter background and screeen is black, I did call OnResume and OnPuase, but it still black.
  When playing game( not loading something), phone call comes, app can go back normally.
  Can anybody help me ?
  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking in the right place, by calling `OnPause`, then `OnResume`.  Its hard to analyze why its not working, without seeing your code.

I can think of a pretty harsh way to handle it:

- set a flag in your Asset loading that indicates that you are loading your assets (make it a class member variable)
- In your `OnPause`, stop any asset loading if your flag is set.
- In your `OnResume`, if your flag is set, start loading the assets all over again.

There could be a more elegant way to deal with it, but with this much info, I don't